# Command not found Ruby - trying to create 24 game

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve the "24" game. The point of the game is to generate 4 random integers from 1-9 and ask the player to use addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division to get the number 24. My code runs fine until a player enters a number, and then I get "Command not found". Can someone please take a look at this:

```
def evaluate (input,solved_v)
    input = eval (input.to_f)
    #convert to a float and then evaluates it; it computes
    if input == 24
        solved_v = true
        puts "great job! you did it!"
    else
        puts "please try again"
    end
end

def test_entry (input)
    if input.scan(%r{[^\d\s()+*/-]}).empty?
        #this scan detects letters and special characters because only numbers work
        true
    else
        false
    end
end


puts
puts "try to use +, -, / or * to"
puts "get 24 from the integers provided"
puts

series = (1..4).collect{ rand(1..9)} 
    #generates 4 random numbers between 1 and 9

for i in series
    puts i
end

puts "Please guess"

solved = false

unless solved = true

    user_input = gets.chomp

    if test_entry(user_input) == true
        evaluate(user_input)
    else
        puts "invalid characters entered"
        puts "please try again"
        puts
    end
end
```

Comment: Please paste the full error, I am not getting that one

Comment: `unless solved = true` should be `unless solved == true`

Comment: @Skram no it shouldn't, it should be `unless solved`.  Similarly, the `test_entry` method should be `def test_entry(input); input.scan(%r{[^\d\s()+*/-]}).empty?; end`

Comment: @pjs `unless solved == true` is valid Ruby code (I've just tested it). `=` is assignment operator, `==` is comparison operator that's the main source of error. `unless solved` is more idiomatic (I think that's how people say this word) when you want to check for any *trueish* values (`1` is trueish too). We don't know what exactly he or she want so I suggest not suggesting this without explanation.

Comment: @DarekNędza yes it's valid, but it's discouraged specifically because it often leads to the accidental assignment fluff committed by OP. Similar to how experienced programmers will tell you to write `1 == value` instead of `value == 1` so that if you accidentally turn it into an assignment the compiler/interpreter will catch it. Ruby provides `unless` as well as `if` so that you can use boolean expressions natively in a readable form with greatly reduced chance of messing it up.

Comment: Well, that's kind of comment is good because it's teach why to use something not what to use.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I took all your advice and found a solution. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your program.

- Don't put spaces between your method names and parentheses.
- `eval` takes a string argument, not a float.
- Ruby passes arguments by value, so `solved_v` isn't going to get
  returned.  Make it the return value of your `evaluate` method.  I'd also
  suggest renaming your methods to express their boolean intent.  See below...
- Don't check boolean expressions for equality to `true` or `false`, just use them.

---

```
def correct?(input)
  if eval(input) == 24
    puts "great job! you did it!"
    true
  else
    puts "please try again"
    false
  end
end

def good_entry?(input)
  input.scan(%r{[^\d\s()+*/-]}).empty?
end
```

and they get used as follows

```
while true
  user_input = gets.chomp
  if good_entry?(user_input)
    break if correct?(user_input)
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Finally, note that you're not actually checking that the input provided by the user uses only the supplied random numbers.

Comment: Why not just use `Integer` instead of `eval`? Something like this: https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/8bf0c72ee50373ca1b06 ps. I think this comments may belong to the Code Review.

Comment: @DarekNędza Fire up `rib` and try running `Integer("1 + 2")` vs `eval("1 + 2")` to see why.

Comment: It's ok because I am `pry`ing a lot.